# Restore/recover Bugzilla on Linux server that has crashed? (can boot to Live CD and mount partition)

Tags: bugzilla

Our bugzilla server crashed.  I can boot via a Live CD and mount the partition but can't boot cause Grub is all jacked up.

It's running Ubuntu 9.10.

I have all of the files from the server as well on an FTP server.

Anyone know how to recover/restore Bugzilla if all I have are the files themselves?  I can't do a mysql backup...at least I don't think I can...since I can't boot off the HDD that has mysql installed.

Any ideas?

Comment: If it is just Grub that is messed up, the disk is fine, the OS is fine, etc I would just look at fixing Grub.  Ask a question about repairing Grub and give details on what is wrong with it.

Comment: Maniac...I did ask about fixing grub.  I've gone through multiple online "fixes" but so far I still end up not being able to boot.  So I figured since this is only doing bugzilla it would be easy enough to move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try copying the files from `/var/lib/mysql` on the old hard disk to the same location on the new disk. I've had success doing that with my server when repartitioning and reinstalling it. After this, simply reinstall BugZilla (you can copy the old apache config from `/etc/apache2` and the webserver files from `/var/www` instead of reinstalling everything) into the same place on the new server.

Comment: OK, I'll try this in the morning and let you know...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can start mysql using chroot.

Boot off the/a live CD. 
Mount the partition of the broken drive. 
 #mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1

chroot into the mounted drive. 
 #chroot /mnt/sda1

In affect you are running on the HDD, you can start up MySQL and dump the data off it.

Fixing grub is not hard and I suggest doing that before declaring the install dead. Then again, Ubuntu 9.10 is old now, it would be a better idea to migrate to 10.04.